# Python: How to use a for-loop or while-loop to alphabetize a list in a file

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am both new to programming and python. I need to read a list in a file, use a while-loop or for-loop to alphabetize that list and then write the alphabetized list to a second file. The file is not sorting and it is not writing to the file.  Any insight or constructive criticism is welcome.

```
unsorted_list = open("unsorted_list.txt", "r")  #open file congaing list
sorted_list = open ("sorted_list.txt", "w")     #open file writing to 
usfl = [unsorted_fruits.read()]                 #create variable to work with list

def insertion_sort(list):                       #this function has sorted other list
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value         
                i = i - 1               
            else:
                break

insertion_sort(usfl)                           #calling the function to sort                                       
print usfl                                     #print list to show its sorted
sfl = usfl
sorted_furits.write(list(sfl))                 #write the sorted list to the file                     

unsorted_fruits.close()                              
sorted_fruits.close()                               
exit()
```

Comment: Post a sample input and expected output(in the question body). I think you need `usfl = unsorted_fruits.readlines()`

Comment: Can you show a small part of your file? And there is a `sorted` function and list get a `sort` method. Maybe you don't have to write a sort yourself.

Comment: Your variable names don't match up. Is unsorted_list the same as unsorted_fruits? And sorted_list = sorted_fruits?

Comment: Is this an assignment and you MUST use a loop? Or why don't you just use `sorted`?

Comment: This is an assignment, we are required to use either a for-loop or a while-loop.  I have worked on this in different forms and at times in sections, I had not noticed I had jumbled the variable names.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If `insertion_sort` worked before, I guess it works now, too. The problem is that `usfl` contains only one element, the content of the file.

If you have a fruit on each line, you can use this to populate your list:

```
usfl = [line.rstrip () for line in unsorted_fruits]
```

or if it is a comma separated list, you can use:

```
usfl = unsorted_fruits.read ().split (',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the way you're handling files.

Try something along the lines of:

```
input_file  = open("unsorted_list.txt", "r")
output_file = open("sorted_list.txt", "w")

#Sorting function

list_of_lines = list(input_file) #Transform your file into a
                                 #list of strings of lines.
sort(list_of_lines)

long_string = "".join(list_of_lines) #Turn your now sorted list
                                     #(e.g. ["cat\n", "dog\n", "ferret\n"]) 
                                     #into one long string 
                                     #(e.g. "cat\ndog\nferret\n").

output_file.write(long_string)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me begin by saying thank you to all the answers.  Using the answer here to guide me in searching and tinkering I have produced code that works as required.

```
infile  = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")  
outfile = open("sorted_fruits.txt", "w")    

all_lines = infile.readlines()              
for line in all_lines:                      
    print line,                             

def insertion_sort(list):                   
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value         
                i = i - 1               
            else:
                break                       

insertion_sort(all_lines)                   
all_sorted = str(all_lines)                 

print all_sorted                            
outfile.write(all_sorted)                   

print "\n"

infile.close()                              
outfile.close()
exit()
```